# Move Zoom In & Out Button in ArcGIS JavaScript Web AppBuilder (Developer Edition Download)

Tags: javascript, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, arcgis-web-appbuilder

After creating a web app in ArcGIS Online, I downloaded the app using the Web AppBuilder for ArcGIS (Developer Edition). Several folders, .json, .html, .js, and .css files are contained within the download. I have been able to modify the header and website color scheme, as well as move the Home button and various other widgets. However, I cannot find any reference to the Zoom Slider. I have found several posts on how to hide the slider, but not within the downloaded AppBuilder developer edition.

How would I move the slider down the page to accommodate a larger header? Where would this code be inserted (in the config.json, index.html, or another file included within the download)?

Comment: Edit the css/style.css at (WebAppBuilderFolder)/client/stemapp/widgets/ZoomSlider

Answer (score 1):

Edit the config.json file in the root directory.

This part specifically:

```
  {
    "uri": "widgets/ZoomSlider/Widget",
    "position": {
      "top": 5,
      "left": 7,
      "relativeTo": "map"
    }
```